# How to cancel std::async when condition is met?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I am running an asynchronous task and want to cancel it when a certain condition (*bool*) is met.

```
void MyClass::createTask()
{
    this->future = std::async(std::launch::async, [this](){
        while(this->CONDITION == false)
        {
            // do work
        }
    });
}

void MyClass::cancelTask()
{
    this->CONDITION = true;
    this->future.get();
}
```

Obviously, calling `MyClass::cancelTask()` would cause a data-race, because `this->CONDITION` is being written to and read from at the same time. So the first thing that came to my mind is to use a `std::mutex`. However that would mean that the task has to lock and unlock the mutex on every new iteration of the while-loop. Since the async task is performance critical, this seems like a bad choice.

Is there a cleaner, and especially a more perfomant way to achieve what I am trying to do? Switching from `std::async` to `std::thread` would be ok if it enabled an efficient solution.

Comment: `std::atomic<bool>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no elegant way to close a thread/async task in C++.

A simple way is to use `std::atomic<bool>` or `std::atomic_flag` instead of a mutex.

If you are familiar with boost library, than you could use `boost::thread` with interruption_points.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this kind of requeirements. I use `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable` and `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` to create tow methods: `pauseThread` and `resumeThread`.

The idea is use the `condition_variable` and `unique_lock` to make the thread wait for a time, for example 5 seconds, and after the time os over the thread continue its execution. But, if you want to interrupt the `condition_variable` you could use its method `notify_one()`.

Using your code, and continue with your idea, i made some changes to your class:

> MODIFICATION: I modify the flag bKeepRunning.

**MyClass.h**

```
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <atomic>

class MyClass
{
    std::atomic<bool> bKeepRunning;

    std::mutex mtx_t;
    std::condition_variable cv_t;
    std::future<void> _future;

public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    void createTask();
    void stopTask();

    void pauseThread(int time);
    void resumeThread();

}
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    bKeepRunning = false;
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::createTask()
{
    bKeepRunning = true;
    _future = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() {
        int counter = 0;
        cout << "Thread running" << endl;
        while (bKeepRunning)
        {
            counter++;
            cout << "Asynchronous thread counter = [" << counter << "]" << endl;
            this->pauseThread(5);//Wait for 5 seconds
        }
        cout << "Thread finished." << endl;
    });
}

void MyClass::stopTask()
{
    cout << "Stoping Thread." << endl;
    bKeepRunning = false;
    resumeThread();
}

void MyClass::pauseThread(int time)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck_t(mtx_t);
    cv_t.wait_for(lck_t, chrono::seconds(time));
}

void MyClass::resumeThread()
{
    cout << "Resumming thread" << endl;
    cv_t.notify_one();
}
```

I made a console sample to show how it works:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "MyClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass app;
    char line[80];

    cout << "Press Enter to stop thread." << endl;
    app.createTask();

    cin.getline(line,80);
    app.stopTask();
}
```

If you need some other period of time to pause your thread, you can try to change the interval and time of `chrono::seconds(time)` to, for example, `chrono::milliseconds(time)` that is using milliseconds.+

At the end, if you execute this sample, you could get an output like:

[image]